# Minecraft Command help: testfor/execute questions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im using command block on a multiplayer map I am creating. Is there any data value that goes up/down when a player looks in the direction of another player? If not, are you able to count how many players that are on a specific team in a set radius and then say that number through /tellraw?

Comment: Flagging question as too broad because it contains two entirely unrelated questions.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes! There is!

If you're looking to teleport somebody, you can determine the direction that they're looking at with this syntax of the `/tp` command.

```
/tp @p [x] [y] [z] [x-look] [y-look]
```

If you're looking to select somebody looking in a certain direction, you can use the `rx`, `rxm`, `ry` and `rym` selector arguments.
For each selector, a float is required as the value to look for. The `ry` and `rx` arguments look for a player with a rotation lower than the given value, while the `rxm` and `rym` arguments look for a player with a rotation greater than the given value.

- The `rx` and `rxm` arguments test for the player's horizontal rotation.
  -90.0 being that he/she is looking straight down and 90.0 for straight up.
- The `ry` amd `rym` arguments test for the player's vertical rotation; whether they are looking North, South, East or West.
  This system branches from the South direction (0d) and moves into negative/positive; East (-90d)/West (90d) and North (180d/-180d).
  It also allows for in-betweens of multiples of 90 degrees, allowing freedom in testing for certain rotations, for example: 45d is South West.

For example, if I would like to test for a player that is looking North West, and straight ahead (at ground level), I would test for a `rx` and `rxm` of 0 (directly ahead) and a `ry` and `rym` of somewhere between North (180d) and West (90d); 135 degrees.

```
 /testfor @a[rx=0,rxm=0,ry=135,rym=135] ...
```

Just note, that this command tests for **exact** rotation, which can be really hard to reach. It'd be better to give leeway either side, for example: 5 degrees.

```
 /testfor @a[rx=5,rxm=-5,ry=140,rym=130] ...
```

---

> If not, are you able to count how many players that are on a specific team in a set radius and then say that number through /tellraw?

This is also achievable. This time, add the `team` selector to your command, and to count, get each player to `/execute @a[...] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players add dummy count 1`, assuming that you have a `dummy` player to take the count, have the score set to 0 and your counting scoreboard is `count`.